# How to insert values into virtual fields

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a learner table that i set values to on a user registration, 'Register(RegisterViewModel model)' in the AccountController.

```
 if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent:false, rememberBrowser:false);


                using (The_FactoryDBContext db = new The_FactoryDBContext())
                    {
                        Learner learner = new Learner();

                        learner.learnerID = User.Identity.GetUserId();
                        learner.llCounter = 0;
                        learner.dtwCounter = 0;
                        learner.ftwCounter = 0;
                        learner.counter = 0;

                        db.Learners.Add(learner);
                        db.SaveChanges();
                    }
                }
       }
```

This is how my learner auto generated class looks with some virtual fields.

```
public partial class Learner
{
    public Learner()
    {
        this.Learner_Treasure = new HashSet<Learner_Treasure>();
    }

    public string learnerID { get; set; }
    public int llCounter { get; set; }
    public int dtwCounter { get; set; }
    public int ftwCounter { get; set; }
    public int counter { get; set; }

    public virtual AspNetUser AspNetUser { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Learner_Treasure> Learner_Treasure { get; set; }
}
```

}

However i get this error upon registration and i dont know how to fix it, can someone help me, or is my code perhaps in the wrong place?

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Learner_AspNetUsers1". The conflict occurred in database "The_Factory", table "dbo.AspNetUsers", column 'Id'.

AspNetUser class

```
public partial class AspNetUser
{
    public AspNetUser()
    {
        this.AspNetUserClaims = new HashSet<AspNetUserClaim>();
        this.AspNetUserLogins = new HashSet<AspNetUserLogin>();
        this.AspNetRoles = new HashSet<AspNetRole>();
    }

    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public bool EmailConfirmed { get; set; }
    public string PasswordHash { get; set; }
    public string SecurityStamp { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public bool PhoneNumberConfirmed { get; set; }
    public bool TwoFactorEnabled { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> LockoutEndDateUtc { get; set; }
    public bool LockoutEnabled { get; set; }
    public int AccessFailedCount { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public int AvatarID { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<AspNetUserClaim> AspNetUserClaims { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<AspNetUserLogin> AspNetUserLogins { get; set; }
    public virtual Avatar Avatar { get; set; }

    public virtual Learner Learner { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<AspNetRole> AspNetRoles { get; set; }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
[ForeignKey("AspNetUser")]
```

over `learnerID` property. The reason is that EF has no clue that you are creating a 1-1 mapping from `learner` to `user` (and that the PK in `learner` is also the FK to `user`). Putting this attribute will tell EF about your design.

Comment: does this devlaration go drirectly above the learnerID property? I  ask because whereever its put, there is an error

Comment: Yes, and please also show any code you've written on `AspNetUser` class. I think you've got a property in `AspNetUser` class like `public Learner Learner{get; set;}` Then you need to add this above it: `[InverseProperty("AspNetUser")]`

Comment: There is a 'public virtual learner Learner{get; set;}' property.

Comment: In addition to the suggestion in the answer, Add `[InverseProperty("AspNetUser")]` to it.

Comment: I still somwhow run into the same brick wall ill edit my question to add the AspNetUser class